# Searching for text then selecting the parent element? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, watir

I'd like to search for text within the html then select the parent of the element so I can use that to store a reference ID as a string.  (I'm using watir to do this as the purpose for it is automated testing)

so here's an example:

```
<html>
     <body>
         <div id="container">
             <span class="story">
                 <span>
                     ref4040
                 </span>
             </span>
             <div id="text">
                 example
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can use ruby to search for the text "example" then select the parent so I can store the reference ID within the span as a string?

(I know you can do it the simple way in this example of selecting the div then the span, but on the project I am actually working on, this is not possible.  The only possible way of doing it is via search for the text then selecting the reference.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the parent element by doing `.parent`.

So you could do something like:

```
browser.div(:text, 'example').parent.span(:class, 'story').text
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it for a generic element? i.e. find an element with text 'example', no matter if it's a `<div>`, `<li>`, `<a>`, `<span>`, etc.?

Comment: @AndréFernandes, you can use `element` (instead of `div`, `span`, etc) to match any tag name. For example, `browser.element(text: 'example')` will find the first match regardless of whether it is a `div`, `span`, etc.

Comment: Worked like a charm!